# Using definition prove that $\frac{1}{n}+(-1)^n$ is not cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Using definition prove that $\frac{1}{n}+(-1)^n$ is not cauchy

Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m=2n+1$ then

$|x_{m}-x_{2n}|=|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|=\bigg|\frac{1}{2n+1}-1-\frac{1}{2n}-1\bigg|=\bigg|2+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\bigg|>2$

thus by definition contradic the definition given an $\epsilon > 0$ we have a $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n,m > N$ we have that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: Sincerely the inequality is always greater than 2, choose an epsilon less than 2 and you will get a contradiction

Comment: rather than a contradiction, you just choose $\varepsilon_0\in(0,2)$ and by the work done above, you have shown the negation of the the sequence being Cauchy

Comment: @CSquared Is my answer correct?

Comment: @DARK yes it correct. was just noting that you don't need to argue by contradiction, since you have already shown the negation of the sequence in question being a Cauchy sequence

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right since, as you say, if $\varepsilon\leq 2$ the definition is not fulfilled.